# Is multiplication by zero clear for and understood by K-3 students?

Tags: primary-education, concept-motivation, curriculum, teacher-preparation, definitions

For K-3 students, perhaps it is not acceptable to introduce *multiplication by zero* as a property or definition. Instead, the child may think about multiplication as, e.g., repeated addition.

Examples of the "repeated addition" conception: $3 × 2 = 3 + 3 $ and $ 4×3 = 4 + 4 +4$.

**My questions:**

> How will students conceive of $ 3 × 0 $?
>
> How should early elementary/primary curricula deal with multiplication by zero?

Comment: I think the graphical approach gets the idea across. You could represent $3\times 1$ by a row of three dots; likewise $3\times 2$ is two rows of three dots; etc. If you asked them to guess what $3\times 0$ was, some would probably tell you you'd have *no* rows so no dots, so the answer is zero. Humans are very good at inductive logic, even if we aren't aware of it.

Comment: Alternatively (following up on @CameronWilliams suggestion) one could regard $3 \times 1$ as "three rows with one dot in each row", $3 \times 2$ as "three rows with two dots in each row", and then $3 \times 0$ would be "three rows with no dots in them" so there are zero dots.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think that the alternative is more clear. We may use sets instead of rows. For example $ 3 × 2 $ as 3 sets each contains 2 elements. For $ 3 × 0 $ it shuld be 3 empty sets. Thanks again.

Comment: No offense meant, @AbdallahAbusharekh, but that's a very mistaken idea. Don't introduce the idea of sets to children. Visual aids are best for children.

Comment: @CameronWilliams, I get your point, but perhaps he's just thinking of unstructured collections rather than rows.

Comment: Perhaps @CameronWilliams you should write your comment into a proper answer so that we can upvote it.

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA Done!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer as per request:

I think the graphical approach gets the idea across. You could represent $3\times 1$ by a row of three dots; likewise, $3\times 2$ is two rows of three dots; etc. If you asked them to guess what $3\times 0$ is, some would probably tell you you'd have *no* rows so no dots, so the answer is zero. Humans are very good at inductive logic, even if we aren't aware of it.

Comment: I do have to say that in my mind I usually interpret $3 \times 2$ to mean "3 groups of 2" to me rather than "2 groups of 3". But I know others interpret it the other way. Still, it's worth keeping in mind with your children.

Comment: Also, a further idea you could add to your answer is to think of it this other way around. $1 \times 3$ is three groups of 1, $2 \times 3$ is three groups of 3, so working backwards, $0 \times 3$ would be three groups of none, so none in total.

Comment: @DavidButlerUofA good point. I don't remember how I thought about it exactly as a kid, I just know it was one of our two ways. These days I think it's pretty interchangeable for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sticking with food math.

You have 4 friends and need 2 candy bars per friend, so 8 bars. Similar, if say, 1 bar per friend, you have 4 bars total. If you have 0 bars per friend, it's 0. But if it's 0 per friend, no matter how many friends you have, you still need 0 candy bars.